# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol exception while parsing xml

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am executing below code:

```
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docBuilder.parse(sourcepath);                  
        node = doc.getElementsByTagName("NAME").item(0);
        node.setTextContent("Bob");

        node = doc.getElementsByTagName("ADDRESS1").item(0);
        node.setTextContent("US");


        node = doc.getElementsByTagName("EMAIL").item(0);
        node.setTextContent("abc@defg.com");




        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();

        node = doc.getElementsByTagName("DATESUBMITTED").item(0);
        node.setTextContent(dateFormat.format(date));


        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        System.out.println(rail_feedback_dest);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(destinationPath));          transformer.transform(source, result);
```

but when i am giving path in a variable "sourcepath" and "destinationPath" it is giving error:java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
but on giving full path instead of providing it in variable, code is working fine....

Comment: and what does sourcepath look like? `MalformedURLException` probably means it is getting the wrong sourcepath.

Comment: What is the types of sourcePath and destinationPath ? URL or String or File ?

Comment: "C:/Users/user123/Desktop/satisfy/Dummy Xmls/Feedback.xml"

Comment: And what does it look like when you don't give the full path, but provide it in a variable? Could you println it / breakpoint it and see what the value of sourcepath is?

Comment: ok.. got it.. quotes are creating problem... thanks